# "Insert on a chain"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, verbs, prepositions

I have some chained methods in my experiment like A→B→C . What is the best of way of expressing putting something new on this chain? Suppose that I want to add D to have A→B→C→D. Do I say I add D on the chain? into the chain? to the chain? etc. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: -1 Please share research you attempted, and any results. Close General Reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In OP's specific case, D is being *added **to** [the end of] the chain*, so "to" is fine. But if the final sequence is A → B → D → C, then D was *added* (*inserted, introduced, linked*, etc.) ***into*** the chain.

Comment: "Insert on a chain" seems awkward to me. What do you think?

Comment: @Noah: I think *"Insert on a chain"* is not something a native speaker would say often, if ever. As my answer implies, *"into"* is the normal preposition, but plain *"to"* is often used after *"add"* where the meaning is *append*.

Comment: What about *insert in a chain*?

Comment: I don't want to be drawn into how acceptable every different preposition might be. Opinions probably differ anyway. For OP's purposes (and yours, I'd have thought), it should suffice to say *"**into**" is the normal preposition* in this context.

Answer (score 1):

Add would be assumed at the end of the chain, although append would be more specific. Or you could say do D after C. With C already known to be part of the chain, it should not cause any confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You would *link* D to C (or to the end of the chain). See the verb *link* in any dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

The terms *append* and *prepend* are common in math and computer science for exactly this kind of thing.

- A→B→C→**D**

  D is appended to the chain.
- **D**→A→B→C

  D is prepended to the chain.

You can also say that the chain is *prefixed* or *suffixed* by D, but these sound awkward (to me) outside the context of natural language.

Comment: This answer can be improved by citing a reputable source.